# not able to sucsessfully pass string value "$10.55" as spring path variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

my controller class is

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/auditregistry/collectionentry/cid/{cid}/collid/{collid}/colldt/{collectiondate}/amount/{amt}")

public ModelAndView saveManualCollection(@PathVariable("cid") Integer custId, @PathVariable("collid") Integer collRtId, @PathVariable("collectiondate") String dt, **@PathVariable("amt") String amount**) throws Exception 
{
    debug("amount recieving=="+amount);
```

and the values that  i am passing to the url are

> /auditregistry/collectionentry/cid/9991/collid/10/colldt/20120726/amount/**$14.55**

when i am trying to print the amount value its printing as "$14" instead of "$14.55" what should i do to print the actual value "$14.55"

any help is very thankfull

Comment: Did you try debugging, is $14.55 coming as it is in Java code. You should probably escape dot(.) in client code

Answer (score 6):

change your RequestMapping to below

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/auditregistry/collectionentry/cid/{cid}/collid/{collid}/colldt/{collectiondate}/amount/{amt:.*}")
```

the change is here repalced **{amt:.*}** insted of **{amt}** in your RequestMapping

Comment: For some reason adding setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false) didn't work for me, but updating the @RequestMapping as suggested does. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain why and how this works? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It's because by default Spring MVC strips everything after `.` and treats it as a file extension (e.g. `/file.txt`). This can be easily fixed. With Spring MVC 3.1 and Java configuration:

```
@Configuration
class Cfg extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        final RequestMappingHandlerMapping mapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        mapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
        return mapping;
    }

}
```

Notice the call to: [`RequestMappingHandlerMapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html#setUseSuffixPatternMatch(boolean)).